# Is it possibl to use one broker for two django project?

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have two project with two celery ,but i used one Redis broker ,does it have problem?i think it has problem,because i have problem in run task,and sometimes tasks do not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different BROKER_URL setting for each project:

project1.settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

project2.settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
```

Comment: can you explain about this?

Comment: Redis instance can have up to 16 different logical databases (0-15), and default database is 0. When your projects omit database number from the BROKER_URL both workers read database 0 and steal tasks from each other.

You can use separate Redis database for each project to avoid this problem.